# Dynamically add fields and send JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm noob in JS. I am making ASP.NET MVC application. I have a partial view, where I want to add a new product.

```
<fieldset>
    <form>
    <legend>Add detail</legend>
    <div>
        <p>
            Select categorie:
            @Html.DropDownList("Categories");
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>
            Select brand:
            @Html.DropDownList("Brands");
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>
            Model name:
            @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.part.parts_model)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.part.parts_model)
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>
            Price:
            @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.part.parts_price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.part.parts_price)
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>
            Amount:
            @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.part.parts_amount)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.part.parts_amount)

        </p>
    </div>

        <div class="details">
            <input type="text" name="details_name" />
            <input type="text" name="details_value" />
            </div>
        <div><p><a class="plus">Add detail</a></p></div>

    <div>
        <input type="file" name="uploadImage" />
    </div>
        </form>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

After user press "Add detail", new fields(same as in class "Details") should be added.
After user press "submit" the new product had to be sent to the server side.

I am trying to add new fields like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on('click', 'a.plus', function() {
        var fld = $(this).closest('div').prev().find('div.details').last(), add=fld.clone().val('');
        fld.after(add)})
})
```

I am looking for help with this, thank you.

Edit:
Erdogan Oksuz helped with dynamic add fields. I still don't know, how to send JSON object to the server side. And one more, is it possible to do it with Razor elements?

Models:

```
public class AddPartViewModel
{
    public bs_parts part { get; set; }
    public List<bs_details> detail { get; set; }
    public bs_images image { get; set; }
}

public partial class bs_parts
{
    public bs_parts()
    {
        this.bs_details = new HashSet<bs_details>();
        this.bs_images = new HashSet<bs_images>();
        this.bs_orders = new HashSet<bs_orders>();
    }

    public decimal parts_id { get; set; }
    public decimal parts_category_id { get; set; }
    public decimal parts_brand_id { get; set; }
    public string parts_model { get; set; }
    public double parts_price { get; set; }
    public int parts_amount { get; set; }

    public virtual bs_brands bs_brands { get; set; }
    public virtual bs_categories bs_categories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<bs_details> bs_details { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<bs_images> bs_images { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<bs_orders> bs_orders { get; set; }
}

public partial class bs_details
{
    public decimal details_id { get; set; }
    public string details_name { get; set; }
    public string details_value { get; set; }
    public decimal details_part_id { get; set; }

    public virtual bs_parts bs_parts { get; set; }
}
```

And my server code(don't look at ides, its for test):

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreatePart(AddPartViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase uploadImage)
    {
        ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(_db.bs_categories, "categories_id", "categories_name");
        ViewBag.Brands = new SelectList(_db.bs_brands, "brands_id", "brands_name");
        if (ModelState.IsValid && model.part != null)
        {
            model.part.parts_brand_id = 3;
            model.part.parts_category_id = 3;
            _db.bs_parts.Add(model.part);
            if (model.detail != null)
            {
                foreach (var details in model.detail)
                {
                    details.details_part_id = 8;
                    _db.bs_details.Add(details);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid && uploadImage!=null)
            {
                byte[] imageData = null;
                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(uploadImage.InputStream))
                {
                    imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(uploadImage.ContentLength);
                }
                model.image.image_part_id = model.part.parts_id;
                model.image.images_image = imageData;
                _db.bs_images.Add(model.image);

            }
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Main");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var $myForm=$("#myForm");

$(".plus").off("click").on("click",function(){
  $(".details").append(`
    <div class="details-part">
      <input class="details_name" type="text" />
      <input class="details_value" type="text" />
    </div>
  `)
});

$("#save-form").off("click").on("click",function(){
  var detailList=[];
  $myForm.find(".details-part").each(function(){
     detailList.push({
        details_value:$(this).find(".details_value").val(),
        details_name:$(this).find(".details_name").val()
      })
   });
  $myForm.find('[name="details"]').val(JSON.stringify(detailList))
  $myForm.submit()
});
```

```css
.plus{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="/yourpath">

        <div class="details">
           <div class="details-part">
            <input class="details_name" type="text" />
            <input class="details_value" type="text" />
           </div>
        </div>
        <div><p><a class="plus">Add detail</a></p></div>

    <div>
        <input type="file" name="uploadImage" />
    </div>
        
    <input type="hidden" name="details"/>
    <div>
        <button id="save-form">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @C.America, don't forget to accept answer in order to help other people

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I will, but my broblem didn't solved yet. I still cant send this new dynamically added items to the server side. Erdogan helped to add new fields.

Comment: @C.America I added form tag click save button then you can see JSON object in developer tools > network tab.

Comment: @ErdoganOksuz sending null. I added my models and c# code in main post. Maybe something wrong with names of added fields?
It was ok, when I tried to send model like this Html.EditorFor(model=>model.detail[0].details_name)

Comment: @C.America I update answer for your model.Check details property in network tab.

Comment: @ErdoganOksuz i don't know, what am I doing wrong, but it is still null :(
you can check image http://savepic.ru/13768514.jpg

Comment: You can add specific fields in your form parameters otherwise your model It look null.Did you change file input name to **image** ?

Comment: @ErdoganOksuz sorry, but i didn't understand, what do you mean about specific fields? Yes I changes, but I'm not wasting time by adding image each time, don't look at it, I'm trying to understand what is wrong with sending model.

Comment: `bs_details partial class` needs  `details_id` and `details_part_id` did you provide this fields?

Comment: @ErdoganOksuz of course I did,you can see this fields in main post.

Comment: Can you send image your Developer tools > Network > Request Form Data?

Comment: @C.America I didn't see all data, Maybe you can send **Right Click Request** > **Copy** > **Copy as cURL(bash)**

Comment: @ErdoganOksuz I posted result in pastebin https://pastebin.com/UTyDaztE
I tryed to add new field of details_name and details_value, so I had couple of this values, and as you can see nothing have been sent

Comment: @ErdoganOksuz when I sent fields like this <input class="copy-input" type="text" name="details_name" /> dev tools shows them, and when i tryed to do the same but with fields like this <input class="details_name" type="text" /> dev tools cant see the values

Comment: @C.America You cannot send same fields in the form, for this reason, I leave name attributes and added here; 
`$myForm.find(".details-part").each(function(){
     detailList.push({
        details_value:$(this).find(".details_value").val(),
        details_name:$(this).find(".details_name").val()
      })
   });
  $myForm.find('[name="details"]').val(JSON.stringify(detailList))`

Comment: @ErdoganOksuz i copy-pasted you code, before show you sended data

Comment: @C.America Something wrong and I don't have any idea for this, Sorry.I hope someone solves this problem.

Comment: It works, when I use attributes like this:
<input name="detail[0].details_name" type="text" />
What if I add a couple, and then would like to delete one of them? Anybody know what to do with this?